# JavaScript Page State

Tags: javascript

I am trying to put a page state together but am having trouble going back to the original home state. After I click Link 1, it goes to that page, but once I click "back" nothing happens and console shows that id name 'back' is a null. I guess because the id doesn't exist in the first page state?

Here are my codes:

```js
const PageState = function() {
  let currentState = new homeState(this);
  this.init = function() {
    this.change(new homeState);
  }
  this.change = function(state) {
    currentState = state;
  }
};

// HOME
const homeState = function(page) {
  document.querySelector('#output-heading').textContent = null;
  document.querySelector('#output-content').innerHTML = `
     <div id="link-1">Link 01</div>
     <div id="link-2">Link 02</div>
     <div id="link-3">Link 03</div>
    `;
};

// LINK 02
const secondState = function(page) {
  document.querySelector('#output-heading').textContent = 'Page 02';
  document.querySelector('#output-content').innerHTML = `
     <p>This is the second page.</p>
     <div id="back">GO BACK</div>
    `;
};

// LINK 03
const thirdState = function(page) {
  document.querySelector('#output-heading').textContent = 'Page 03';
  document.querySelector('#output-content').innerHTML = `
    <p>This is the third page.</p>
    <div id="back">GO BACK</div>
    `;
};

// INIT PAGESTATE
const page = new PageState();

// INIT FIRST STATE
page.init();

// UI VARS
const one = document.getElementById('link-1'),
  two = document.getElementById('link-2'),
  three = document.getElementById('link-3');
back = document.getElementById('back');

one.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  page.change(new firstState);
  e.preventDefault();
});

two.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  page.change(new secondState);
  e.preventDefault();
});

three.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  page.change(new thirdState);
  e.preventDefault();
});

back.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  page.change(new homeState);
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<div class="container-output">
  <h4 id="output-heading"></h4>
  <div id="output-content"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After I click Link 1, it goes to that page, but once I click "back" nothing happens and console shows that id name 'back' is a null. I guess because the id doesn't exist in the first page state?

Yes that is the problem.

You could instead do something like this:

```js
const homeState = function() {
  document.querySelector("#output-heading").textContent = null;
  document.querySelector("#output-content").innerHTML = `
      <div id="link-1">Link 01</div>
      <div id="link-2">Link 02</div>
      <div id="link-3">Link 03</div>
  `;
  const one = document.getElementById("link-1");
  const two = document.getElementById("link-2");
  const three = document.getElementById("link-3");

  one.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    generatePageState("Page 01", "This is the first page.");
  });

  two.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    generatePageState("Page 02", "This is the second page.");
  });

  three.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    generatePageState("Page 03", "This is the third page.");
  });
};

const generatePageState = function(heading, text) {
  document.querySelector("#output-heading").textContent = heading;
  document.querySelector("#output-content").innerHTML = `
      <p>${text}.</p>
      <div id="back">GO BACK</div>
  `;
  const back = document.getElementById("back");
  back.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    homeState();
  });
};

homeState();
```

```html
<div class="container-output">
  <h4 id="output-heading"></h4>
  <div id="output-content"></div>
</div>
```

After navigating to a page `#output-content` is set dynamically. The links are replaced by the paragraph and the button, so now that the button is in the layout we can add the event listener to it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! This is exactly what I was looking for. I will study and test this code. Thank you so much again!